# How to get the offsets programmatically with Kafka 1.0

Tags: apache-kafka

The `OffsetRequest` has been deprecated for a while, along with almost all the other classes in `kafka.api` and now has been removed in 1.0. However, neither [the deprecation message](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/017a21c6044189abe40b2b8b09ba51447646136e/core/src/main/scala/kafka/api/OffsetRequest.scala#L26) nor [the docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_100_notable) explain what can be used instead.

The [FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIaccuratelygetoffsetsofmessagesforacertaintimestampusingOffsetRequest?) is not helpful for this topic.

There are [CLI tools](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-ConsumerOffsetChecker) for this, but I have not found any advice on doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

The classes in `kafka.api` are for the old clients (in Scala) that are deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

The new Java clients are using the classes defined in `org.apache.kafka.common.requests`.

The class `org.apache.kafka.common.requests.ListOffsetRequest` is the replacement for the old `OffsetRequest`.

The following methods from `KafkaConsumer` can be used to retrieve offsets (they all send a `ListOffsetRequest` from the client):

- beginningOffsets() : http://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#beginningOffsets-java.util.Collection-
- endOffsets(): http://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-
- offsetsForTimes(): http://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes-java.util.Map-